# How To Get Data To TextBox C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2017

I need you help i have stored procedure Which Return Last Number Of CustomerID + 1 : Like This

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Last_Customer]

as

begin

Select IsNull(MAX (CustomerID),0) +1 From CustomersTbl


End
```

Now in the Project I have Class Called DataAccessLayer and it has the following functions :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Test.Data_Layer
{
    class DataAccessLayer
    {
        SqlConnection sqlconnection;

        public DataAccessLayer()
        {
            sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connSQLServer"].ConnectionString);
        }

        //Method To Open Connection
        public void Open()
        {
            if (sqlconnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlconnection.Open();
            }
        }

        //Method To Close Connection
        public void Close()
        {
            if (sqlconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlconnection.Close();
            }
        }
        //Method To Read Data From Database
        public DataTable SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
            if(param !=null)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        //Method To Insert , Update And Delete From Database ( You Need To Open And Close The Connection )
        public void ExecuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
            if (param != null)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

So I have create Class In Business Layer Called CLS_GetLastRecord and it have the follow Code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.Business_Layer
{
    class CLS_GetLastRecord
    {
        public DataTable GetLastRecord()
        {
            Data_Layer.DataAccessLayer DAL = new Data_Layer.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt = DAL.SelectData("Get_Last_Customer", null);
            DAL.Close();
            return Dt;
        }

    }
}
```

Ok Now is the last Step which is calling this Function To Form So i create Form with textbox :
on load action i put this code to get the last number of customerid + 1 but it dosent work :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Test.PL
{
    public partial class FrmGetLastRecord : Form
    {
        Business_Layer.CLS_GetLastRecord GetLastRecord = new Business_Layer.CLS_GetLastRecord();

        public FrmGetLastRecord()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FrmGetLastRecord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = GetLastRecord.GetLastRecord().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea how to deal with it ?

Comment: Do you notice that if CustomersTbl has no rows, you are *not* getting 1, right?

Comment: Yes  i notice but iam not getting 1 you are right

Comment: Thanks i got it now by edit the load form action to : 

    private void FrmGetLastRecord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable tbl = GetLastRecord.GetLastRecord();
        textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows[0][0])).ToString();
    }